# If I put the "compileSdk" value above 32, attributes disappear from the layout editor

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-layout-editor

I booted up Android Studio today to start a new project. I chose an empty template etc. I checked out the layout editor and noticed it was missing some basic attributes like "background."

[my android studio version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zn1a4.png)

I'm a bit confused about this and wanted to ask. I checked for an update and see one is available. (Eel) I'm not in a good spot to reinstall the SDK. Is that what would correct this all, or is it something else?

[missing attrs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nReB.png)

Of course, I first cleared caches and restarting. Searched a bit. Ended up deleting that in /tmp or ~/.android cache. (Linux) off a suggestion found on stack overflow, but only to the same result.

I have at least 5 other projects, so I loaded up an old project. The once missing attributes were present. The difference was those use a compileSdk of 32 in the build.gradle. The new project was 33.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the latest stable Android Studio release - which is currently Giraffe. Same project and same result. Still missing attributes.

Then I tried the Android Studio offering in the Linux repos. (apt) That installed Android Studio Electric Eel. (2022.1.1 Patch 2) All attributes popped up as expected.